# Dropping a pin in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

In Google Maps for iPhone, I am able to get the approximate address (e.g 4590-4615 StackExchange Lane) for someone (or myself) by just dropping the pin. Is there a way to to do this in Google Maps ?

I tried using right click -> `Directions to here` . This does drop a pin where I want it but it either only gives only the street name or the coordinates (19.746024, -155.588379).

Am I missing a step or is there a better way to get the same feature I have on my iPhone ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just right-click on the map and choose `What's here?`. This should give you the approximate address.

Comment: Sweet ! It seems to also matter what zoom you are at but I will take it ! Thanks ! :D